# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux

Hello guys i have some problem with typescript/redux. in reducer i can't access to action.type.
here's my types file:

```
export interface MoviesState {
  movies: any[];
  loading: boolean;
  error: null | string;
}

export enum MoviesActionsTypes {
  FETCH_MOVIES = "FETCH_MOVIES",
  FETCH_MOVIES_SUCCESS = "FETCH_MOVIES_SUCCESS",
  FETCH_MOVIES_ERROR = "FETCH_MOVIES_ERROR",
}

interface FetchMoviesAction {
  type: MoviesActionsTypes.FETCH_MOVIES;
}

interface FetchMoviesSuccessAction {
  type: MoviesActionsTypes.FETCH_MOVIES_SUCCESS;
  payload: any[];
}

interface FetchMoviesErrorAction {
  type: MoviesActionsTypes.FETCH_MOVIES_ERROR;
  payload: string;
}

export type MoviesAction =
  | FetchMoviesAction
  | FetchMoviesErrorAction
  | FetchMoviesSuccessAction;
```

and my reducer:

```
import { MoviesState, MoviesActionsTypes, MoviesAction } from "../types";

const initialState: MoviesState = {
  movies: [],
  loading: false,
  error: null,
};

const movieReducer = (
  action: MoviesAction,
  state = initialState,
): MoviesState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case MoviesActionsTypes.FETCH_MOVIES:
      return { loading: true, error: null, movies: [] };
    case MoviesActionsTypes.FETCH_MOVIES_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, error: null, movies: action.payload };
    case MoviesActionsTypes.FETCH_MOVIES_ERROR:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload, movies: [] };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default movieReducer;
```

console log tells: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type'). don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: Could it be because the position of the `movieReducer` arguments? From the `useReducer` documentation, `state` comes first, then the `action`.

Comment: Nevermind, I tested it with your code and it works 100%

Comment: From what I tested, it is possible to get the error when you pass `null` to the `dispatch`

Comment: yep, that was a problem. there was eslint error "default parameters should be last default-param-last". now I fix it. thank you a lot